# Distinguish Wifi connection for application access

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, internet-connection

We are developing an enterprise access mobile application which needs to run on particular wi-fi access.

To put it more simple, in the building where the application need to be accessed is having 4 wifi routers. but the requirement is that the application should run only when the device is connected to one specific wifi router.

As we are developing javascript (Cordova) based application, it is making sense if we some controls in that. by the way the application is targeted for both iOS and Android.

Any work in this area is really appreciated.

Thanks
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this GitHub fork could help you (IOS is added in this fork): https://github.com/companje/org.apache.cordova.wifiinfo

**Install**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/companje/org.apache.cordova.wifiinfo
```

**Get WifiInfo**

```
navigator.wifi.getWifiInfo(success, error, options);
```

**OnSuccessData**

```
{
    connection: {
    BSSID: BSSID,
    HiddenSSID: HiddenSSID,
    SSID: SSID,
    MacAddress: MacAddress,
    IpAddressInt: IpAddressInt,
    IpAddress: IpAddress,
    NetworkId: NetworkId,
    RSSI: RSSI,
    LinkSpeed: LinkSpeed
    },

    networks: [
    {
        BSSID: BSSID,
        SSID: SSID,
        frequency: frequency,
        level: level,
        capabilities: capabilities
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth I couldn't get this to install, receiving the error:  Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.wifiinfo':Error: Expected plugin to have ID "org.apache.cordova.network-information" but got "cordova-plugin-network-information".  I ran the command:  [cordova plugin add https://github.com/dippi/org.apache.cordova.wifiinfo]  It might work using Plugman but I don't know.

Comment: You can install it using `cordova plugin add https://github.com/companje/org.apache.cordova.wifiinfo`

Comment: I ended up abandoning this approach, using device.uuid instead to uniquely (attempt to) identify users.  It's now working as expected (with the caveat that if a user un-installs/re-installs my app they'll have to re-enter their phone number once).